# I am unable to join IRC channels from within emacs

Tags: emacs, irc

I'm not sure what isn't working, but I run `M-x irc` and it brings up the usual irc buffer with a lengthy intro message. It sets my nick to my username, which isn't my irc registered nick so I then issue the command `/nick ActualNick` and then it tells me to identify, as expected. But then, I issue the command `/msg NickServ identify <passwd>` and nothing happens! After that I can type `/me` and see that my nick is `ActualNick` but nothing else - why would this be happening?

Comment: To rule out the server as the cause, is this currently working in a non-Emacs IRC client? (or, if you only have Emacs, with `M-x erc`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try starting IRC using `C-u M-x irc`. This will prompt for connection details.

Comment: This worked for me, not sure why the identifying command wasnt doing anything but identifying via the prompts from here worked..thank you